# Wagmi useContractWrite, add Arguments to pass to function

Tags: transactions, wagmi

Hey im trying to use wagmi to write  this function to a smart contract inside my application, it’s for purchasing tickets and is a payable Function: buyEntry(uint256 _raffleId,uint256 _id,address _collection,uint256 _tokenIdUsed), and requires these parameters, and this is the code I have tried without success, thanks

```
import { usePrepareContractWrite, useContractWrite, useWaitForTransaction } from 'wagmi';

function BuyEntry({ raffleId, id, collection, tokenIdUsed, etherAmount }) {
  const { config, error } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: '0xAC3DC1c1cdaDDb75002fCEA1Bd808aB6C4477213',
    abi: [
      {
        name: 'buyEntry',
        type: 'function',
        stateMutability: 'payable',
        inputs: [
          { name: 'raffleId', type: 'uint256' },
          { name: 'id', type: 'uint256' },
          { name: 'collection', type: 'address' },
          { name: 'tokenIdUsed', type: 'uint256' },
        ],
        outputs: [],
      },
    ],
    functionName: 'buyEntry',
    args: [raffleId, id, collection, tokenIdUsed],
    value: etherAmount,
  });
  
  const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config);
  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransaction({ hash: data?.hash });

  const handleBuyEntry = () => {
    // Removed the write() function call from here
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button disabled={!write} onClick={() => write()}>
        Buy Entry
      </button>
      {error && (
        <div>An error occurred preparing the transaction: {error.message}</div>
      )}
      {isLoading && <div>Buying entry...</div>}
      {isSuccess && (
        <div>
          Entry purchased successfully!
          <div>
            <a href={`https://etherscan.io/tx/${data?.hash}`}>View on Etherscan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

function BuyEntryButton() {
  return (
    <BuyEntry
      raffleId="7"
      id="27"
      collection="0xd2057fd21F0619099Bd9d4ABDA17953368139D8C"
      tokenIdUsed="1"
      etherAmount="0.001"
    />
  );
}

export default BuyEntryButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button Buy Entry you have to call write like this:

```
<button disabled={!write} onClick={() => write?.()}>
  Buy Entry
</button>
```

I also recommend you to take `error` from `useContractWrite` instead of `usePrepareContractWrite`